# A simple Javascript game called Traceball

Tags: javascript

I need help/advice on how to sort out an issue I have

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TalvinJoshuaJacobs/TraceBall/master/src

My task is to code a game in Javascript and HTML where the user has to escape an enemy.

I am struggling with telling the the red box "obstacle" to follow me (the green box)

Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:20px solid #000000;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(130, 130, "green", 10, 120);
    myObstacle  = new component(130, 130, "red", 300, 120);    
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1550;
        this.canvas.height = 872;
        this.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
            myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
        })
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }    
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
        myGameArea.stop();
    } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
        myGamePiece.x = myGameArea.x;
        myGamePiece.y = myGameArea.y;
    }
        myObstacle.x -= 5;        
        myObstacle.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
}


</script>

<p>Avoid hitting the obstacle, or else the game will stop.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for implementation suggestions, you should look into event sourcing.  You could make your game piece an event emitter and trigger an event that will move your obstacle when the event is fired.

If you're using a bundler like webpack or something similar you can use the nodejs EventEmitter, but that's not available in the browser by default.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/EventEmitter

Check out this repo for a naive implementation of an event emitter that can be used in the browser: https://github.com/parallaxisjones/microevent.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:20px solid #000000;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(130, 130, "green", 10, 120);
    myObstacle  = new component(130, 130, "red", 300, 120);
    myGamePiece.on('move', function(params){
        // do something with myObstacle
        myObstacle.updatePosition(params);
    })
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1550;
        this.canvas.height = 872;
        this.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
            myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
        })
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
        //fire an event that can be subscribed to by other things
        this.trigger('move', this)
    }    
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}
// register components as an event emitter with the microevent lib linked
MicroEvent.mixin(component)
function updateGameArea() {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
        myGameArea.stop();
    } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
        myGamePiece.x = myGameArea.x;
        myGamePiece.y = myGameArea.y;
    }
        myObstacle.x -= 5;        
        myObstacle.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
}


</script>

<p>Avoid hitting the obstacle, or else the game will stop.</p>
</body>
</html>
```